# How to update OpenSSL version 1.0.1 14 Mar 2014 to OpenSSL versions beginning with 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za?

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I am using eclipse (Luna) on window 7. and i have  to update my apk on google play store it showed me a warning **"Violation of the dangerous products provision of the Content Policy and section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.
The vulnerabilities were fixed in OpenSSL versions beginning with 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za."**
And i check my older version is 1.0.1 how should i upgrade my OpenSSL version??
Please suggest me step by step Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to update your openSSl version in your server.

Comment: How server side OpenSSL content include in .apk file? Could you explain a bit more please.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs